# How do I SELECT and COUNT rows in SQL?

Tags: php, sql

How do I get the results and count the results in **one query**? (Im using PDO statements)

```
SELECT * FROM table; // gets results
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table; // counts results
```

Comment: If you used one query, what would you want your results to look like?

Comment: Also, what flavor of sql are you using?

Comment: is `GROUP BY...WITH ROLLUP` a possibility?

Comment: Why does it need to be one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM table");
$count = mysql_num_rows( $result);
```

Using PDO:

```
$statement = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM table');
$statement->execute();
$count = $statement->rowCount();
```

Comment: This doesnt work with a PDO statement, is there something like this that works with PDO?

Comment: Your OP mentions nothing about PDO, but you can use the rowCount function, although it is not as reliable as the above - http://us3.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Answer (score 1):

This will put the record count at the end of each row.

```
SELECT *
   , COUNT(1) OVER () AS RecordCount
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *, (select count(*) FROM table) ct FROM table
```

Comment: This is actually two queries against the table, but returned in one result set.

Comment: -1 downvote for not answering OP's question: request is for one query.

Comment: It is one statement that returns one response.  Can you point me to a reference that defines a SQL statement with a subselect as not "one query"?

Comment: I do not have a definition for you.  The problem I had with this answer was that if you look at an execution plan for the query, comparing it to either my answer, or from nickb, this answer is twice as slow.  This is due to the second table scan of `table`.  I believe it was the intention of the OP to ask for a query which does not require the second scan.

Comment: I interpreted that he didn't want to incur the latency of two separate fetches across his network between the web server and database.  I'm glad you found a more optimal solution, but disagree with your opinion of wrongdoing.

Comment: I understand your assumption now, and tried to remove my downvote, but am unable to since the question has not been edited since my vote.

Comment: No worries there, quick draw, but you might be well served to set your own assumptions aside and test whether your "COUNT(1) OVER ()" really is twice as fast.  What I see in PostgreSQL, running against an OUI (mac prefix) table of 15K rows, is that the subselect query ran consistently as fast or faster.

Answer (score 0):

you should execute only one query...

```
$sql = SELECT * FROM table;
$res = mysql_query($sql);
```

you can have total count by mysql_num_rows(); function.. like this ..

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($res);
```